# Hypothesis testing on tossing the coin n times

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, inference

You toss the coin n times, and you have observed 60% of times, it is heads.

How large does n need to be in order to achieve 95% confidence that it is not a fair coin?

=======

Attempt: Basically use Binomial distribution, but I have no idea how to take account of the 60% number into my calculation.

$\mu +/- Z_\alpha \frac{S}{\sqrt(n)}, \text{so I have,   }  0.6 * \frac{\sqrt(n)}{0.6*\sqrt{0.6*0.4}} = Z_{0.05} =1.96$, so $n$ = 1.6

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want $n$ large enough that a confidence
interval of the form $\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$ where $X$ is the number of heads and $\hat p = X/n,$ does not include $0.5.$

Roughly speaking the standard error is $\sqrt{.6(.4)/n}$
and the margin of error is about $2\sqrt{.6(.4)/n}\approx 0.98/\sqrt{n}.$ And you want the margin error to be less
than $0.1,$ so something around $n = 96$ should suffice. I show
examples with $n=100$ below.

```r
n = 100;  x = 60;  z = qnorm(c(.025,.975))
CI = .6 + z*sqrt(.24/100);  CI
[1] 0.5039818 0.6960182
```

A superior kind of CI due to Agresti and Coull uses
the point estimate $\tilde p = (x+2)/(n+4) = 62/104 = 0.5962$ and the endpoints are at $\tilde p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\tilde p(1-\tilde p)/104}.$ This interval also just misses covering $1/2.$

```r
p.est=(60+2)/(10+4)
p.est + qnorm(c(.025, .975)) * sqrt( p.est*(1-p.est)/104 )
[1] 0.5018524 0.6904553
```

Finally, a Jeffries 95% CI uses quantiles $0.025$ and $0.975$
of the distribution $\mathsf{BETA}(60+0.5, 40+0.5),$ so that the interval is $(0.5023,0.6920).$

```r
qbeta(c(.025, .975), 60.5, 40.5)
[1] 0.5022567 0.6920477
```

Depending on the kind of interval you are using and whether you
want the *smallest* number just large enough so that the CI doesn't
contain $1/2,$ I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: I think it is possible to solve this problem using a Bayesian approach as I saw [here](https://jwmi.github.io/BMS/chapter1-foundations.pdf), however, I don't really know why the y-axis of figure 4 is not in the 0 to 1 range.

Comment: Link is to a whole book, not sure I see the relevance.